# Batch scripting for executing SQL scripts in a directory

Tags: sql, batch-file

I want to develop a batch script which will execute each  .sql SQL scripts present in the folder where the batch file is placed to and record the logs to a filename_sqloutput.txt file .
The condition is : If any script gives any error message like column name incorrect , or table name etc. The script execution should stop immediately and further scripts should not executed .

I tried with the below code: But its not working as  even if the script is giving errors in the output file . The script execution is not stopping ..

Need your help !!!

```
@echo off
for /f %%a IN ('dir /b *.sql') do (call sqlcmd -S AMRVSP000000318 -i %%a  -o"%%~na_sqloutput.txt" 

findstr "Msg" %%~na_sqloutput.txt >nul & if %errorlevel% EQU 1 (exit)  else (echo Successfully executed %%~na_sqloutput.txt) 
)
pause
```

Comment: Change `findstr "Msg" %%~na_sqloutput.txt >nul & if %errorlevel% EQU 1 (exit)  else (echo Successfully executed %%~na_sqloutput.txt)` by `findstr "Msg" %%~na_sqloutput.txt >nul && exit || echo Successfully executed %%~na_sqloutput.txt`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[FINDSTR will set %ERRORLEVEL% as follows](https://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html):

> - 0 (False) a match is found in at least one line of at least one file.
> - 1 (True) if a match is not found in any line of any file, (or if the file is not found at all).
> - 2 Wrong syntax
>
> An invalid switch will only print an error message in error stream.

Moreover, follow [EnableDelayedExpansion](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) article and rewrite the script to more readable structure:

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
for /f %%a IN ('dir /b *.sql') do (
    call sqlcmd -S AMRVSP000000318 -i %%a  -o"%%~na_sqloutput.txt" 

    findstr "Msg" "%%~na_sqloutput.txt" 2>NUL
    if !errorlevel! EQU 0 (
        echo error occured %%~na_sqloutput.txt
        rem pause to see error
        pause
        exit /B
    ) else (
        echo Successfully executed %%~na_sqloutput.txt
    ) 
)
pause
```

Comment: Thank you very much JosefZ !!! You have solved my problem with this query .. Thanks a ton .

Comment: Hello JosefZ,  Can you help me with one more modification ..My script folder will have numbered scripts like 1.abc.sql   2. ert.sql ,   3.tyh.sql  The batch script should ask the sql file name from which the execution should start and once that is provided it should start from that script to the end of files in directory and if any error in script execution . The execution should end

Comment: @NITESHHEGDE Of course, I can however you should ask another question for such huge topic expansion, providing more detailed and more precise description of your problem. If I understand it, ask via [`SET /P "prefix=enter sql starting number"`](https://ss64.com/nt/set.html) and parse `for /F "usebackq delims=." %%G in ("%%~a") do if %%G GEQ %prefix% ( …`. Reference: https://ss64.com/nt/. Please take the 2-minute [tour]. 
Moreover, open [Help] and read at least [ask] and  [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

.... if errorlevel 1 (exit...

`%errorlevel%` is the initial value of `errorlevel` as it stands when the `for` is encountered.

See endless SO articles about using `delayed expansion` as another solution.

This syntax means "if the current `errorlevel` is 1 or greater dothis else dothat"